# Stop function to load when click checkbox in ASP NET VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'd like some help with the following situation.

I have a method (function) that loads an org chart as follows:

**PAGE chart.aspx.vb**

```vb
partial class display chart
  Sub MyChart()
    'My Code Here
  End Sub
End class
```

I have a checkbox button on my login page, when it is ticked will stop the above function to run and the org chart will not load when user is logged in.

**PAGE login.aspx**

```html
<div>
  <asp:button id="login" Text="login" runat="server"></button>
  <asp:checkbox id="mytick" Text="Tick Me" runat="server" />
</div>
```

**PAGE login.aspx.vb**

```vb
class newclass
  Sub newsub
    If mythic.Checked Then
      'help me here - User who don't want to see the chart
    Else
       'display the chart
    End If
End class
```

I am looking for a solution in VB NET only, and
I would like to thank in advance for your support

Comment: There is no `virtual` keyword in VB. Can you show us the *actual* code? You may want something like `If mytick.Checked Then Session("showChart") = False` and then examine the value of `Session("showChart")` when deciding if the chart should be shown.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not doing the check within the function itself? If you do your if/then statement within your MyChart() and have it exit the sub (those are subroutines, btw, not functions. Functions return results) if the checkbox is checked otherwise proceed.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have a org chart working perfectly fine, but I would like to allow users to click a textbook if they don't want to see the chart. Thanks for your comment.